# SQL Server : table change tracking

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, audit

I have the below tables and would like to track changes which happen in the `DishButton` table. If a button is added, or deleted and when this was done.

Can someone please advise?

```
 select DishID, DishName, Price 
 From DishTable 

 Select ButtonID, ButtonName
 From ButtonTable 

 Select DishButtonID, DishID, ButtonID
 From DishButtons
```

A dish can have multiple buttons. When the buttons is removed, the record is deleted from the table. If the button is added, a new record is inserted.

Comment: You have to read about `trigger` for the database you are using.

Comment: sql server t-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a table to track the DishButtons table. Write a trigger to have all the data you need to get inserted in that table whenever some changes happen in DishButtons table.